# reduction of complexity numbers procedure

Tags: javascript, digits

I'm looking for a solution to my problem

if I have numbers

```
var first = 14:1
var next = 13:8
```

therefore, the console should give a result

```
console.log(first_result)  // 141
console.log(next_result)  // 141
```

and I want the numbers counted like `141` in the result to be

simply if there is an example

`13:8` if both digits are the last, 3 and 8 are bigger than ten, then turn the tens and turn and insert into the previous number and leave the rest at the end

so `13:8` becomes `141`

Comment: You mean you have strings containing `"14:1"` and `"13:8"`? It's not very clear what the rules for generating the result are.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the last digits bigger than 10..?

Comment: So, if I follow... `13:8` becomes `[13, 8]`, then you add `3 + 8` and get `11`.  `11` is more than `10`, so then you get `[13+1, 1]` or `[14, 1]` and thus `141`.  Is that right?

Comment: @Redu yes curetly

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes this right

Comment: @DaveNewton  14:1 4 and 1 are not greater than 9, so the numbers remain in the same position

thus 141

and the example where 13: 8 3 and 8 is 11

so 1 (and add 3 to 3) and add 1 at the end

thus 141

Comment: What have you tried? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It's best to show your good-faith effort instead of just dropping requirements on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with strings, then you just simply split the string on `:` to get your 2 numbers.

To get the last digit, you can simply use `x % 10`.  Then just add the numbers and see what happens.

```js
let value = '13:8',
    nums = value.split(':').map(Number),
    last_digits = nums.map(x => x % 10),
    // or last_digits.reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0)
    sum = last_digits[0] + last_digits[1],
    result;

if (sum > 10) {
    nums[0]++;
    nums[1] = sum - 10;  // or, probably sum % 10
}

result = nums.join('');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm new here I can not give evaluation reviews sorry and thank you very much

Comment: if I can ask for a repair 7:22 gives the result but they need it to become the number "722" in doing so, he should proceed exactly the opposite 722 the result should therefore be correct 29 because 7 and 2 are not greater than 9